# Looping programmed labels and buttons

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uibutton, uilabel

In the last viewcontroller of my app I wrote a code which creates a number of labels which are filled with random characters from a set

Under the labels textfields appear where the user should match the characters from the labels. When he hits the button, his answer is checked. If the answer is right the score is updated.

After that the score label should update, and new text for the labels with characters should be generated and shown, but that's where I get stuck... My instinct would be to add a loop to the code in the viewDidLoad, but as the code to check the answer is in the buttonAction function outside of the viewDidLoad, I don't know how to do this...

Here is some code from my app which might clarify things. I deleted quite a lot of straightforward code and put a comment line in just for this example.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // variables are declared, the number of labels is calculated based on the frame size
    // the text for the labels is calculated based on a function in a separate class I wrote

            var a = 0
            while a < numberOfLabels {
                // the UILabels are made and filled
                // the corresponding UITextFields are made
                a += 1
                labelX += labelWidth
            }
            // then here the button is coded, the last lines are:
            myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(myButton)
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    var a = 0
    var rightAnswer = false
    var userInput: [String] = Array()
    while a < numberOfLabels.shared.category! {
        if let theLabel = self.view.viewWithTag(a) as? UITextField {
            let tekstInput = theLabel.text
            userInput.insert(tekstInput!, at:a-1)
        }
        a = a + 1
    }
    let controle = Controle()
    rightAnswer = controle.checkAnswer(userAnswer: userInput)
    if rightAnswer {
        if var score = PassScore.shared.category {
        score += 1
        PassScore.shared.category = score
        }
        else {
            var score = 1
            PassScore.shared.category = score
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: The labels are generated on runtime or you have used the Storyboard?

Comment: They are generated without the Storyboard just with code, so runtime.

Comment: And your problem is  to re-initialize those labels with new characters and also the textfield, is it right or i misunderstood something?

Comment: Exactly! They should re-initialize after the buttonAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your initialization code in a function

```
func setupLabels() {
    var a = 0
        while a < numberOfLabels {
            // the UILabels are made and filled
            // the corresponding UITextFields are made
            a += 1
            labelX += labelWidth
        }
}
```

And call it whenever you need it:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLabels()
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    //...
    setupLabels()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a great idea. I just get an error in the function. "Use of unresolved identifier 'view' in the code "let viewWidth = view.frame.width", "view.addSubview(myLabel)" and 'Use of unresolved identifier 'buttonAction'' in myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside) Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Just to clarify what I did: when I add the function to the viewDidLoad() I get an error in the buttonAction function because setupLabels isn't available there. So I moved this function to a separate class. I guess just view.frame.width isn't enough in that class, I should add a reference to the view which I mean, but I'm not sure how to do that...